# Discord.js TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')

Tags: discord.js

I understand that after the discord.js 14 update the intents import was no longer valid, and you had to use GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, yet when I put it into my cod[enter image description here as shown in the screenshot below, it comes up with ReferenceError: GatewayIntentBits is not defined.
I tried to add GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5afV.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the **GatewayIntentBits** object.

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages] }); // Add your other intents
```

I also use Discord JS v14, and with the version I use, the following also works for me:

```js
const { Client } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({ intents: ["Guilds", "GuildMessages"] }); // Add other necessary intents
```

For the updated list of intents:
https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/GatewayIntentBits#AutoModerationConfiguration

---

**Edit:**

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
// Import the proper identifier for mongoose here

const client = new Client({ intents: [ 
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildModeration, 
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildEmojisAndStickers, 
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildIntegrations, 
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildWebhooks, 
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildInvites, 
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates
]});
```

Comment: Should this work now? 
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("mongoose");
const client = new Client({
 intents: [
  GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
  Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
  Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
  Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS,
  Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS,
  Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INTEGRATIONS,
  Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_WEBHOOKS,
  Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES,
  Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
  
 ]
});

Comment: As I get this error now SyntaxError: Identifier 'Client' has already been declared

Comment: That's because you're importing Client twice. const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js"); const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("mongoose");

Comment: I edited my answer. Check the edit section at the bottom. I removed GuildBans as that's deprecated and has been replaced with GuildModeration. That should work now, all you have to do is use the proper identifier for importing mongoose, which I do not know as I don't use it but from what I've read it's:

const mongoose = require("mongoose");